# How do I convert strings of digits into lists of digits with proper spacing?

Tags: python

I have a string of digits:

```
grades= '50 20 1 55 90'
```

How do I want convert this into a lists? When I try to use the list() function I get

```
['5', '0', ' ', '2', '0', ' ', '1', ' ', '5', '5', ' ', '9', '0']
```

Which makes life hard man. I need them in the format:

```
[50, 20, 1, 55, 90]
```

I tried coming up with a solution of my own which would loop through each element, checking if the string was a digit, and then appending them together until it got to a space, which would make the whole appended digit be appended to another list. This seemed overly complex. There **must** be another way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on whitespace with [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and convert each element to an integer:

```
[int(i) for i in grades.split()]
```

`str.split()` with no arguments, or `None` as the first argument, splits on arbitrary width whitespace, removing any leading or trailing whitespace.

Demo:

```
>>> grades = '50 20 1 55 90'
>>> grades.split()
['50', '20', '1', '55', '90']
>>> [int(i) for i in grades.split()]
[50, 20, 1, 55, 90]
```